# Removing elements in ArrayList with certain size

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist, size

So I'm currently stuck on one of my programs. I have to use a for loop to remove all elements in the ArrayList that's greater than 4. I have no idea how to do this. Someone help?

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class P4E
{
    public static void main( String args[] )
        {
            ArrayList<String> universities = new ArrayList<String>();
            universities.add("Princeton");
            universities.add("UCSD");
            universities.add("UCLA");
            universities.add("SDSU");
            universities.add("UCI");
            int size = universities.size();
            System.out.println( "The size of the ArrayList is: " + size);
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("Now using a for-each loop");
            System.out.println("");
            for (String a : universities)
                {
                    System.out.println( a );
                }//end for-each
            System.out.println( "" );
            System.out.println( "Now using a for loop" );
            System.out.println( "" );
            for (int i = 0; i < universities.size(); i++)
                {
                    if (universities.get(i) > 4 )
                        {
                           universities.remove(i); 
                        }//end if-statement
                }//end for loop
        }//end main
}
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to remove elements at *index* greater than 4?  Your elements themselves are `String`s; they are not comparable with `4`.

Answer (score 2):

Use the Java 8 `removeIf` default method on `List`:

```
universities.removeIf(u -> u.length() > 4);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to remove elements that are larger than 4 characters, this will work:

```
for (int i = 0; i < universities.size(); i++)
{
    System.out.println("checking "+universities.get(i));
    if (universities.get(i).length() > 4 )
        {
           universities.remove(i);
           i--;
        }//end if-statement
}//end for loop
```

The `.length()` is necessary because you're interested in the size of the `string`, you can't compare a `string` to an `int` directly. The `i--;` ensures that you don't skip over elements as the size of the list changes.

The `System.out.println` is to show you what elements it is checking, so you can see that you're walking through the list correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `if(universities.get(i) > 4)`

Do this:

```
for (int i = size; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if (i > 4 )
        universities.remove(i);  // Shorten to only 1 line instead of brackets
}//end for loop
```

**Reason**

You want to remove the university at point `i` in this case, not get the university object. When you call `universities.get(i)` it returns the Object in the `universities` ArrayList

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that `i` advances to the next value even after a `remove()` call, meaning that your code will skip some items.

Here is what's happening: let's say you want to delete all numbers 4 and above from this list: `{9 5 7 4 3}`. When `i` is zero, your algorithm will find `9` and remove it. Now `i` is `1`, but your list is `{5 7 4 3}`, so `5` at index zero will never be checked again.

One solution is to iterate in reverse order:

```
for (int i = universities.size() - 1; i >= 0 ; i--) {
    if (universities.get(i).length() > 4 ) {
        universities.remove(i); 
    }//end if-statement
}//end for loop
```

Now that `i` goes down instead of going up it does not matter whether the list shrinks or not.

Answer (score 0):

With current code problem is in the fact that you increasing i every time, while sometimes you remove element which cause indexes for elements to the left to be shifted. This results in the fact that you skip check for some elements. Example:

Initial array: [5,6,7], index i = 0.
You removed element at index 0 - array became [6,7], then you increase i and it became 1 - so index for next element to check is 1 and this reffer to 7, not to 6. Result - you didn't check 6.

Solutions:

1) Add `i--;` immediately after `universities.remove(i);`

2) Iterate in descending order: `for (int i = 0; i < universities.size(); i++)` -> `for (int i = universities.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)`

3) Use java streams:

```
universities = universities.stream()
                           .filter(e -> e > 4)
                           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you mean by greater than 4? If you meant length of the String greater than 4, then here is the solution. Replace the 2nd for loop with the code below.

```
int i = 0;
while(i<universities.size()) {
    if (universities.get(i).length() > 4 ) {
        universities.remove(i); 
    } else {
        i++;
    }
}
```